# Flash Builder 4.5 list issue

Tags: flash, adobe

I have list populated with different data from PHP and when pressed it opens a URL, but when I return to the list from the browser, it has the selection I made to go to browser still selected. So how do I reset the selection? By the way, its a flex mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to reset the List uses

```
list.selectedIndex = -1
```